# CSS - How to remove content on small screen while applying before and after selector

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a unique problem I want to hide content of my `li` on small screen. I know we have properties like `display:none` `visibility:hidde` or `color:transparent`. But i dont want that. I want complete removal of content but I want to apply `::before` and `::after` selector.

Here is my html

```
    <ul>
        <li>Job posted</li>
        <li>Offers received</li>
    </ul>
```

My css

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

  li::before {
    content: counter(step);
    display: block;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    line-height: 1.2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
    counter-increment: step;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.5rem solid red;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding-top: 0.4rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.2rem;
  }

  li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0.1rem;
    width: 100%;
    top: 1.5rem;
    background-color: green;
    left: 45%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make li font size 0 your ::after ::before will be as it is and your text of li will not display.

```
@media(max-width: 767px){
  li{
    font-size: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code
html

```
 <ul>
        <li><span>Job posted</span></li>
        <li><span>Offers received</span></li>
    </ul>
```

css

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    li span{
      display:none;
    }
  }
```

Comment: dont we have any other way other than span ?

Comment: no way bro.. only u have reduce font size or text-indent method

Comment: As far as I know, I have been watching tutorials, the point is we should not change the semantics just because we want to achieve something which we are unable to do. There is no reason why we should use span in li.

Answer (score 0):

content:initial will remove the content itself and hence other properities will also be not applied.

```
li:after{
    content:initial;
}
```